# Begins with string or not in regular expression

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying simplify the rows below to a single row:

```
sed -i 's/-XX\:PermSize=128m\s//g' /usr/share/hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh
sed -i 's/-XX\:MaxPermSize=128m\s//g' /usr/share/hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh
```

I try use something similar of this `-XX\:(?:Max|)PermSize=128m\s`, but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -ir 's/-XX\:(Max)?PermSize=128m\s//g' /usr/share/hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh
```

Better add `r` than with all those escape. If you are using GNU sed.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `(?:Max|)` is a *non-capturing*  group and it is not compliant with the POSIX regex engine that `sed` uses. You are using a BRE POSIX engine, so, to use a capturing group, you need to use `\(...\)` and to use an alternation operator, you need `\|`.

You may use

```
sed -i 's/-XX:\(Max\)\?PermSize=128m\s//g' /usr/share/hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh
```

This is a BRE POSIX expression, thus `\(Max\)\?` matches an optional `Max` character sequence.

Or,

```
sed -i -E 's/-XX:(Max)?PermSize=128m\s//g' /usr/share/hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh
```

The `-E` option enables the ERE POSIX syntax, an optional `Max` character sequence is defined with `(Max)?`.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/iCMN34)

```
s="ABC-XX:PermSize=128m DEF-XX:MaxPermSize=128m "
sed 's/-XX:\(Max\)\?PermSize=128m\s//g' <<< "$s"
# => ABCDEF
sed -E 's/-XX:(Max)?PermSize=128m\s//g' <<< "$s"
# => ABCDEF
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make `Max` optional in an optional group `(Max)?` :

```
-XX\:(max)?PermSize=128m\s
```

For example:

```
sed -i 's/-XX\:(Max)?PermSize=128m\s//g' /usr/share/hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sed -i 's/-XX\:\(Max\)?PermSize=128m\s//g' /usr/share/hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh
```